# Problem dynamically building a structured HTML table using DIV tags

Tags: python, html, css, wsgi, dynamically-generated

I have a Python program that outputs its data into a web page.  The data is hierarchical but not consistent.  Table row one may have 2 children only and table row two may have 1 child who has 2 children who have 3 children each.  There is a constraint of only 3 generations per parent (e.g. 4 columns of output).  I have written the code to build the output using a dynamic DIV within a DIV approach, but I am struggling getting the columns to consistently line up.  Regardless of the number of data points, I need each column to line up and appear as if it were one consistent table with no whitespace.  Each "cell" DIV needs to keep a consistent width and the broader container needs to span the whole width of the table.

Here is my current style sheet:

```
    <style>


    .rTableMain {
       display: table;
       width: 90%;
       border: none;
       margin: auto;
    }
    .rTable {
       display: table;
       width: 100%
    }
    .rTableRow {
       display: table-row;
       height: 50px;
    }
    .rTableHeading {
       display: table-header-group;
       background-color: #ddd;
    }
    .rTableCell, .rTableHead {
       display: table-cell;
       padding: 3px 3px;
       width: 250px;
       //float: left;
       vertical-align: middle;
       //border: 1px solid #999999;
    }
    .rTableCellLF {
       display: table-cell;
       padding: 10px 10px;
       width: 200px;
       max-width: 200px;
       //float: left;
       vertical-align: middle;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size: 28px;
       color: #ffff99;
       background-color: #25274d;
       border: 1px solid #999999;
    }
    .rTableCellLT {
       display: table-cell;
       padding: 3px 10px;
       width: 200px;
       max-width: 200px;
       //float: left;
       vertical-align: middle;
       font-size: 22px;
       color: #6699CC;
       background-color: #464866;
       border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    }
    .rTableCellMT {
       display: table-cell;
       padding: 3px 3px;
       width: 200px;
       max-width: 200px;
       //float: left;
       vertical-align: middle;
       font-size: 18px;
       color: #000044;
       background-color: #aaabb8;
       border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    }
    .rTableCellST {
       display: table-cell;
       padding: 3px 3px;
       width: 200px;
       max-width: 200px;
       //float: left;
       vertical-align: middle;
       font-size: 12px;
       color: #000055;
       background-color: #2e9cca;
       border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    }

    .rTableHeading {
       display: table-header-group;
       background-color: #ddd;
       font-weight: bold;
    }
    .rTableFoot {
       display: table-footer-group;
       font-weight: bold;
       background-color: #ddd;
    }
    .rTableBody {
       display: table-row-group;
    }
</STYLE>
```

Here is a sample of the generated HTML code:

```
<DIV class="rTableMain">
<DIV class="rTableRow">
<DIV class="rTableCellLF">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</DIV>
<DIV class="rTableCell">
<DIV class="rTable">
<DIV class="rTableRow">
<DIV class="rTableCellLT">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV class="rTableRow">
<DIV class="rTableCellLT">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV class="rTableMain">
<DIV class="rTableRow">
<DIV class="rTableCellLF">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</DIV>
<DIV class="rTableCell">
<DIV class="rTable">
<DIV class="rTableRow">
<DIV class="rTableCellLT">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</DIV>
<DIV class="rTableCell">
<DIV class="rTable">
<DIV class="rTableRow">
<DIV class="rTableCellMT">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</DIV>
<DIV class="rTableCell">
<DIV class="rTable">
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV class="rTableRow">
<DIV class="rTableCellMT">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</DIV>
<DIV class="rTableCell">
<DIV class="rTable">
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV class="rTableRow">
<DIV class="rTableCellMT">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</DIV>
<DIV class="rTableCell">
<DIV class="rTable">
<DIV class="rTableRow">
<DIV class="rTableCellST">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV class="rTableRow">
<DIV class="rTableCellST">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV class="rTableRow">
<DIV class="rTableCellLT">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
```

It's probably pretty clear I am not a very skilled CSS programmer so i appreciate the tips along the way.  Just please keep in mind that the HTML is coming from a Python source that's iterating over the data.  If I knew the exact contents before I started building the table, I would do this very differently.  And as much as I appreciate (and may later be asking) for help on the generator code, right now, just looking for CSS / HTML help.

Thanks in advance!  I can't tell you how much help everyone on stackoverflow has been.  You are all thankless heroes who help us all achieve what seemed programatically impossible when we started!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, clearly not a question either worth asking or easy to understand.  I did figure it out if anyone else has as similar issue.  It really came down to better management of my DIV tags and set sizing.

Here's the updated style sheet:

```
 <style>


        .rTableMain {
           display: table;
           //width: 90%;
           border: none;
           margin: left;
        }
        .rTable {
           display: table;
           float: left;
           //width: 100%
        }
        .rTableRow {
           display: table-row;
           height: 50px;
        }
        .rTableHeading {
           display: table-header-group;
           background-color: #ddd;
        }
        .rTableCell, .rTableHead {
           display: table-cell;
           padding: 3px 3px;
           //width: 250px;
           float: left;
           vertical-align: middle;
           //border: 1px solid #999999;
        }
        .rTableCellLF {
           display: table-cell;
           padding: 10px 10px;
           width: 250px;
           //min-width: 200px;
           align: left;
           vertical-align: middle;
           font-weight: bold;
           font-size: 28px;
           color: #ffff99;
           background-color: #25274d;
           border: 1px solid #999999;
        }
        .rTableCellLT {
           display: table-cell;
           padding: 3px 10px;
           width: 250px;
           //min-width: 200px;
           //float: left;
           vertical-align: middle;
           font-size: 22px;
           color: #6699CC;
           background-color: #464866;
           border: 1px solid #ffffff;
        }
        .rTableCellMT {
           display: table-cell;
           padding: 3px 5px;
           width: 250px;
           //min-width: 200px;
           //float: left;
           vertical-align: middle;
           font-size: 18px;
           color: #000044;
           background-color: #aaabb8;
           border: 1px solid #ffffff;
        }
        .rTableCellST {
           display: table-cell;
           padding: 3px 5px;
           width: 250px;
           //min-width: 200px;
           //float: left;
           vertical-align: middle;
           font-size: 12px;
           color: #000055;
           background-color: #2e9cca;
           border: 1px solid #ffffff;
        }

        .rTableHeading {
           display: table-header-group;
           background-color: #ddd;
           font-weight: bold;
        }
        .rTableFoot {
           display: table-footer-group;
           font-weight: bold;
           background-color: #ddd;
        }
        .rTableBody {
           display: table-row-group;
        }
    </STYLE>
```